# Vaadin grid: binding to dynamic filter variable when using dom-repeat

Tags: polymer, vaadin, dom-repeat

I am using the vaadin data grid and the `dom-repeat` template, in order to create [a grid with dynamic columns](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-grid/3.0.2/demo/columns.html#dynamic-columns-using-dom-repeat). I am also using a filter in the grid's footer.

I need placeholder text within that filter's input text field, so I have to set up the input tag. The part that is a problem is the `value`. In the Vaadin grid's [documentation](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-grid/3.0.2/demo/sorting-filtering.html#filtering-with-data-provider), this is a statically-named variable equal to the column name, prepended with `_filter` and then appended with the value of the text field (`::input`).

If I were to hard-code it as `_inputHost::input` it would bind to the dynamically-generated property for the "host" column, but only for this column. It also causes the sorting to break.

In the example below, I've used `_filterXXXXXXX::input`. What should I be using instead?

HTML:

```
<template>
   <vaadin-grid id="grid" data-provider="[[dataProvider]]" size= "[[size]]">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[columns]]" as="column">
        <vaadin-grid-column>
          <template class="header">[[column]]</template>
          <template>[[get(column, item)]]</template>
          <template class="footer">
            <vaadin-grid-filter aria-label="[[column]]" path="[[column]]" value="[[_filterColumn]]">
              <input placeholder="[[column]]" slot="filter" value="{{_filterXXXXXXX::input}}" focus-target>
            </vaadin-grid-filter>
          </template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>
      </template>
   </vaadin-grid>
</template>
```

JS:

```
this.dataProvider = function(params, callback) 
{
    var items = [];
    items.push ({ID:100, host:"foo.com", rank:5});
    items.push ({ID:101, host:"bar.com", rank:8});
    items.push ({ID:102, host:"meh.com", rank:15});
    this.size = items.length;
    callback(items);
}
this.columns = [];
this.columns.push ("ID", "host");
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I never used `vaadin-grid` before sorry if I'm wrong.

I think `_filterXXXXXXX` can be any variable but if you use plain string, the variable will attach to host so you should use another variable instead. I think one of simplest way is use `item` variable (`column` in your case) such as `item.filter`.

So your code should be

```
<vaadin-grid-filter aria-label="[[column]]" path="[[column]]" value="[[column.filter]]">
  <input placeholder="[[column]]" slot="filter" value="{{column.filter::input}}" focus-target>
</vaadin-grid-filter>
```

Of course I didn't test it sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately, while this does populate the placeholder text, it breaks the filtering. When one enters text into the filter text field, the dataProvider is never called, so no filter function can be called. Instead I see a JS error in the console:  


`TypeError: can't assign to property "filter" on "host": not an object `  

Where "host" is the column name.

Comment: Oh my bad, I should notice this. Your `columns` should be array of object which it can has property. Is `dataProvider` work before? may be it break because of this error.